80s 90s Sci Fi Movie - one scene with flying knife auto aiming at a protagonist saved by lifting a chair
I have watched this movie as a kid about 20 years ago, my memory is sketchy, but one scene stuck.
Scene:
Cantina or bar. Protagonist gets surprise attacked by someone launching a self propelled flying knife, which at first floats in mid air for several seconds of anticipation, and finally auto-aims / homes towards the protagonist. Protagonist manages to raise a chair last second however, the knife gets stuck in the chair instead of his chest. 
Facts:
Sci-fi
from 70, 80, early 90 (most likely 80s)     
Uncertainties:
On weird planet, in the future.
Ernest Borgnine might be in it,although I might be mixing up another movie.
The knife, as I remember, was very simple looking dark hilt like so (seen from the top):
 

self propelled flying knifes, in films of this era, always make me think of phantasm; but I don't think anything else matches

although it's not Phantasm, thank you for trying, this one will be tough to identify

I know, I know! It's not a movie, but a TV mini-series. L'isola del tesoro aka Treasure Island in Outer Space.

It is based on the novel Treasure Island by Robert Louis Stevenson,
  setting the story in space in the year 2300. - Wikipedia


Can you tell us why you think this is the answer? Any details? A screenshot, perhaps?

Martin is 100% right although his link takes us to the wrong IMDB page...
It is indeed L'isola del tesoro., from there it was easy to find a youtube clip of the scene I described...

Martin thank you so much, I thought this was unanswerable question as my memory of the scene was very faded. I remembered it as a movie, but it was probably played in two parts on Polish TV back in 1990 or so when I watched it..

Could it possibly be a dart instead of a knife, and it end up in a wall not a chair? Take a look at this scene from the movie Dune: 



Thank you for trying. However, it is not Dune. Very similar circumstance though.

The only old movie I know that has a homing knife is The Shadow(1994)
Probably isn't what you are looking for though.

Thanks for trying. It is not The Shadow, that movie does bring back memories though.

If the knife was made of white crystal, you may be thinking of Doctor Mordrid - a low-budget fantasy film from 1992. Among the weapons utilized by Mordrid are several crystal knives which are shaped exactly like your drawing. There's also a character who looks somewhat like Ernest Borgnine with a beard (it was Ritch Brinkley).
I don't remember one of Mordrid's knives going into a chair, but I haven't seen the film in years. In the trailer below, you can see Mordrid flinging one of the knives at his enemy around the 0:30 mark (the crystal glows as it flies through the air). In the movie itself, the knives are given a lot more screen-time and are used in combat at least twice.




Appreciate the effort, unfortunately, that is not it. I don't think I can remember any more details to make this easier.
